# Including Prior Week's Data from 8/4 Going Forward VBA Code

Tags: ms-access, vba, days

I run this code weekly and I am trying to retrieve data from 8/4 until current. The month of August ran where each previous week appeared on the report, but now that it is September, August data went away. Can you assist me in pointing in the direction where changing the code to include each prior week's data starting 8/4 going forward?

```
Function getDates(Optional forDate As String = "1/31/1999") As String Dim rst As Recordset
getDateRange = vbNullString


If forDate = "1/31/1999" Then
    forDate = DateAdd("d", -1, Date)
End If

If DatePart("d", DateAdd("d", 1, forDate)) = 1 Then
eom = True
End If

Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT Day, FiscalMonth, FiscalYear from tbl_Calendar where FiscalYear = (SELECT FIscalYear from tbl_Calendar where day = #" & _
Format(forDate, "Short Date") & "#) and FiscalMonth = (SELECT FiscalMonth from tbl_Calendar where day = #" & _
Format(forDate, "Short Date") & "#)")


If rst.EOF Then Exit Function
rst.MoveLast
rst.MoveFirst
getDates = CStr(rst.Fields("day").Value) & ";"
rst.MoveLast
If DateDiff("d", rst.Fields("day").Value, forDate) < 0 Then
    eom = "False"
Else
    eom = rst.Fields("FiscalMonth").Value & ", " & rst.Fields("FiscalYear").Value
End If
getDates = getDates & IIf(DateDiff("d", rst.Fields("day").Value, forDate) < 0, CStr(forDate), CStr(rst.Fields("day").Value)) & ";" & eom
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: We can't see your report, and we can't see your `tbl_Calendar` table. Your code might probably do what you want when just adding an `ORDER BY` clause to the query. "Change the code to include certain dates" doesn't mean anything to me, because I don't know what the result of the function is used for. Your function seems to return a string containing two dates (separated by a comma), a semicolon and a True/False flag for "EndOfMonth". But it does neither contain anything related to weeks nor to 8/4 (=2? Or #08/04/1999#?. Please describe what you expect the funtion to do.

Answer (score 0):

First, always handle dates as *dates*, not strings, not numbers, no exceptions.

Then, to find primo of previous week, you can use:

```
PrimoPreviousWeek = DateWeekFirst(DateAdd("ww", -1, Date()))
```

using:

```
Public Function DateWeekFirst( _
  ByVal datDate As Date, _
  Optional ByVal lngFirstDayOfWeek As VbDayOfWeek = vbUseSystemDayOfWeek) _
  As Date

' Returns the first date of the week of datDate.
' lngFirstDayOfWeek defines the first weekday of the week.

  DateWeekFirst = DateAdd("d", vbSunday - Weekday(datDate, lngFirstDayOfWeek), datDate)

End Function
```

Also, use specific formatting of string expressions for date values:

```
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT Day, FiscalMonth, FiscalYear from tbl_Calendar where FiscalYear = (SELECT FIscalYear from tbl_Calendar where day = #" & _
Format(forDate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#) and FiscalMonth = (SELECT FiscalMonth from tbl_Calendar where day = #" & _
Format(forDate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#)")
```

Then proceed with a *complete rewrite* of your code to use data type **Date** and no strings.